# output param on simplejdbccall

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have a stored procedure with a single integer output param and 5 varchar input params, no matter what I've tried I can't seem to get the output param back. I've ran the sproc on the db and it comes back with data, so I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone know how to get an output param back from simplejdbccall?

I have something like this:

```
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall =
        new SimpleJdbcCall( getDatasourceForEnvironment() ).withProcedureName( "_Get_Id" ).declareParameters(
            new SqlParameter( "MyID", Types.VARCHAR ), new SqlParameter( "MySourceID", Types.VARCHAR ),
            new SqlParameter( "MyLocationID", Types.VARCHAR ), new SqlParameter( "MyVisitID", Types.VARCHAR ),
            new SqlParameter( "MyVisitDate", Types.VARCHAR ) );

    HashMap< String, String > input = new HashMap< String, String >();
    input.put( "MyID", myObj.getMyID() );
    input.put( "MySourceID", myObj.getMySourceID() );
    input.put( "MyLocationID", myObj.getMyLocationID() );
    input.put( "MyVisitID", myObj.getMyVisitID() );
    input.put( "MyVisitDate", myObj.getMyVisitDate() );

    System.out.println( simpleJdbcCall.execute( input ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

There were 2 things I had wrong:

1. I was connected to the wrong database. Writing a more granular unit
   test revealed my error.
2. Since the return from "execute" is a map, the output params are case
   sensitive.

Long story short, there isn't anything special you need to do - Spring includes the output params by default. Furthermore, `MapSqlParameterSource` is a much cleaner way to go with these sorts of methods.

Comment: Spring does not return OUT parameters by default when you call a function(not procedure) and expect a return value as well as OUT params. The best way is to always define `new SqlParameter()` as `new SqlInOutParameter()` so spring will update the out params in the map with the return values. Not sure about any performance impact though